# httptest.Server overwriting custom http.Request.Context while using httptest.Server.Client.Do()

Tags: unit-testing, go, http, testing, handler

I'm writing a unit test for an HTTP handler using `httptest.Server`. The unit test is implemented by creating a new request using `http.NewRequest` and sending the reqeust to the httptest.Server using `httptest.Server.Client.Do(req)`.

I am unable to change the context of the newly created `http.Request`.

Here is the implementation of the unit test:

```golang
type CtxKey string

const (
    CtxKeyOwner CtxKey = "owner"
)

func TestCtxInjection(t *testing.T) {
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        value := ctx.Value(CtxKeyOwner)
        if value == nil {
            t.Error("Custom context value is missing")
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(value)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })

    ts := httptest.NewServer(handler)
    defer ts.Close()

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, ts.URL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
        return
    }

    ctx := context.WithValue(req.Context(), CtxKeyOwner, "custom-value")
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)

    res, err := ts.Client().Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    if res.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        t.Error("Wrong status code")
    }
}
```

The problem is only occuring if the request is sent using `httptest.Server.Client.Do()` or any other method of the http client. If the ServeHTTP method of the handler is called directly the error will not occur.

I wanted to inject a new context into the `http.Request` struct and access the Value of it in my handler.

Comment: HTTP the protocol, has no knowledge of Go's `context.Context`. Also Go's `net/http` will NOT send Contexts over HTTP, i.e. the context you set in the _outgoing_ request which is then sent by the client, will NOT be re-created by the server in the _incoming_ request that the handler has access to. The context of the outgoing request is a different _thing_ from the context of the incoming request.

Comment: So should it be tested using the ServeHTTP(w, r) directly?

Comment: You cannot send information over HTTP using context.Context. If you need to send information over HTTP then you need to use HTTP-specific elements, i.e. the request's URL (path or query parameters), the request's HTTP headers, or the request's Body. If you want the information that was sent using HTTP-specific elements to also be available in the incoming request's context, then you need "middleware" in your http.ServeMux which will extract that information from the HTTP-specific elements, store it in the request's context, and then pass the request to the handler.